# How to use Angularjs with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I want to use `Angularjs` with `TypeScript`.

To solve `TS2095: Could not find symbol 'angular'` error, I downloaded `ts` files from [here](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/) and added references to `controllers.ts` like this:

```
/// <reference path="angular.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
var mathML = angular.module('mathML', []);
```

But I still have similar error like this:

```
angular.d.ts(33,28): error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'JQuery'.
```

How can I solve this error?
Is there better way to setup environment to use `Angularjs` with `TypeScript`?

Comment: If you use `tsd` it sets up the paths for you http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the following directory structure :

```
|- angular
    |- angular.d.ts
|- jquery
    |- jquery.d.ts
|- mathML.ts
```

I was able to get the following sample code to compile without errors.

```
/// <reference path="angular/angular.d.ts" />
var mathML = angular.module('mathML', []);
```

The angular.d.ts file references the jquery.d.ts file using a relative path.  The directory structure is pretty standard for typescript code.

Comment: Sadly, I am consuming these from NuGet using a package manager that does not unpack them into this hierarchy. I would really like to see the developer rework this into something that behaves correctly without having to manually copy files.

Comment: Does the directory hierarchy really matter?  Should you be able to `/// <reference.../>` the type definitions wherever they are (e.g. `"../../some/path/angular.d.ts"`)?

Comment: @threed it doesn't really matter.  I just said that it is pretty standard to use that path structure.  The directory structure will constitute what goes inside the ```<reference />``` but it doesn't have to be the exact structure I used.